# runing docker container can't find copied script in dockerimage

Tags: dockerfile, docker-image

My docker file looks like this:

```
    WORKDIR $BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR
    ENV TEMPLATECONF=$BUILD_INPUT_DIR/$PROJECT/sources/meta-$PROJECT/custom
    COPY prep.sh /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/
    COPY fetch-repos.sh /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/
    USER root
    RUN chmod +x /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/prep.sh
    RUN chmod +x /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/fetch-repos.sh
    RUN ls -l /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/*.sh
    CMD ["sh","-c", "./home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/prep.sh && bitbake $PROJECT"]
```

I run the container like this in azure ACR:

```
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '2460-ACR-connection-TMM'
        command: 'login'
    - script: |
        docker run 2460testacr.azurecr.io/2460testacr.2460testacr.azurecr.io:$(tag)
```

But I have got this error, would you help?

> /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/cce02da3-0534-40a8-81c5-52ed45134050.sh
> sh: ./home/rtr2460/yocto/input/prep.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

> ./root/prep.sh: No such file or directory

Tells you that the file at that location does not exist or the user has no access rights to that location. You will need to find the exact location where this path is being assumed in your configuration tries to use this path. It is either legitimate or not.

If it is legitimate, then there are two possibilities: it is either missing or your user does not have the necessary privileges.

If it is a privilege problem, then you can add a line that adds the necessary privileges. Otherwise, if it is missing, then you will need to find out why it is missing. Chances are that your

```
COPY prep.sh /home/$USER_NAME/yocto/input/
```

line is copying the file to the wrong location.

Otherwise, if it is illegitimate, then there is a bug in your configuration (that you can find by searching for anything related to this filename) and fix it.

Comment: I updated it to the right path  but stillsame